# Почему не корректно работает декларация с кодом из CDN?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Переписываю нативный JavaScript на TypeScript. Столкнулся с проблемой использования сторонних скриптов из CDN.

Для валидации телефона, даты и прочего я использую [IMask](https://imask.js.org/), я скопировал содержимое CDN файла себе в проект и подключаю его через `import`, на js все работает корректно, фрагмент для примера:

```
import "/js/moduls/external/imask.js";

const phoneInput = document.querySelector("input[type='tel']");
const imask =IMask.createMask({ mask: "+{7}(000)000-00-00" });

phoneInput.addEventListener('input', e => {
    phoneInput.value = imask.resolve(phoneInput.value);
    console.log('.isComplete', imask.isComplete);
});
```

Для ts рядом с `imask.js` создал `imask.d.ts` добавил декларацию:

```
// imask.d.ts

export default function IMask(): void {
    function createMask({ mask: string }): void
}
```

В таком варианте ошибка

> Не удается найти имя "IMask".

Я не правильно записал декларацию? Может тут надо другим способом описать Imask?

В [Гайде IMask](https://imask.js.org/guide.html) есть вариант установить библиотеку через npm, в таком случае скорее всего все будет работать, но такой вариант меня не устаивает, мне нужно именно минималистичное решение, не хочу создавать node_modules и тянуть кучу зависимостей.

Comment: `IMask.createMask` тут ты вызываешь статическое поле, а объявил как обчное

Comment: Да, действительно. Переписал декларацию, убрал class (в исходном js все на функциях): ` export default function IMask(): void {
    function createMask({ mask: string }): void
} ` В ts убрал "new": ` import "./external/imask.js"

const phoneInput = document.querySelector("input[type='tel']") as HTMLInputElement;
const imask = IMask.createMask({ mask: "+{7}(000)000-00-00" }); ` Ошибка "Не удается найти имя IMask" (

Comment: ты неправильно определяешь `IMask` - где ты взял пример для `.d.ts`?

Comment: Все, что тебе надо было сделать - в прошлом варианте дописать `static`